# Fatal error: in wordpress/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php EC2 Bitnami

Tags: php, wordpress, update, ec2, bitnami

Tengo esta instancia en **AWS EC2** en una pila de Bitnami. Hoy recibí este error, nunca había visto algo así y antes de hacer cualquier cambio me gustaría saber alguna consideración antes. Antes de restaurar quisiera saber si puedo solucionarlo desde los archivos.

```
@include 
base64_decode("L29wdC9iaXRuYW1pL3dvcmRwcmVzcy93cC1pbmNsdWRlcy9pbWFnZXMvd3BpY29ucy0zeC5wbmc=");
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function absint() in /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp- 
includes/class-wpdb.php:2162 Stack trace: #0 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class- 
wpdb.php(2004): wpdb->parse_db_host() #1 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class- 
wpdb.php(773): wpdb->db_connect() #2 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/load.php(582): wpdb- 
>__construct() #3 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-settings.php(124): require_wp_db() #4 
/bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php(104): require_once('...') #5 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp- 
load.php(50): require_once('...') #6 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php(13): 
require_once('...') #7 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/index.php(1): require('...') #8 {main} thrown in 
/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 2162

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_die() in /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp- 
includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php:239 Stack trace: #0 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp- 
includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(154): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler- 
>display_default_error_template() #1 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error- 
handler.php(58): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template() #2 [internal function]: 
WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #3 {main} thrown in /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class- 
wp-fatal-error-handler.php on line 239
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que varios archivos se rompieron o no encuentra la ruta correcta, de ahi el error.